# Why does continuation start before the GetResult()?

Tags: c#, async-await

```
class MyAwaitable
{
    public MyAwaiter GetAwaiter()
    {
        return new MyAwaiter();
    }
    public class MyAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
    {
        public bool IsCompleted { get; }
        public void GetResult()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GetResult().");
        }
        public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Continuation begins.");
            continuation();
            Console.WriteLine("Continuation ends.");
        }
    }
}



class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        await new MyAwaitable();
        Console.WriteLine("The last code.");
    }
}
```

Output:

> Continuation begins.
>
> GetResult().
>
> The last code.
>
> Continuation ends.

## Question

I really don't understand why `Continuation begins.` came before `GetResult().`. In my intuition,  the `GetResult()` should come first.

Why does continuation start before the `GetResult()`?

Comment: Just as a side note, calling `continuation` inside `OnCompleted` could potentially lead to a stack overflow, even if the user code looks quite iterative (see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pQrino)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`continuation` is the delegate which is executed when the thing being awaited completes. Normally the `TaskAwaiter` being awaited will store the `continuation` in a field, and will run it when the `Task` completes.

The compiler-generated state machine uses this to advance to the next state, which in turn will call `.GetResult()` on the thing being awaited (both to get a result, and throw any exceptions);

So the `continuation` is a delegate which ends up calling `GetResult()`.

You can find where `OnCompleted` is called [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs,131). [`continuation`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs,116) is the result of [`AsyncMethodBuilderCore.GetCompletionAction`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs,902) which creates it from [`MoveNextRunner.Run`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs,1057), which [calls `MoveNext` on the state machine](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs,1076).

If you look at the [compiler-generated code for your async method](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQBEJinANjASQDsYIFsBjCAgWwAdcIaITYBLAeyIBoATEANQAfAAIAGAAQiAjAG4AsAChxU6QFYFyyTIB0AJTgk2zHQGEO9NowQBlMgDc2VZJqUiAzFIBME0xIDeShLBUp4iABxSAGwSALIAFACUAUEhaSIAnBJEEADucQCeAIK5UGwwUMCMSZppAL5KDYpKLco+scWl5ZWMSoGK6Z4dJWWkCBIA4hAwI+VkSanB/WnpAOzZeYWzYzWLEk2D3ltdYxIgEgQAchwwbGAF5vSMt1x7yyvBHhLAHBy4F8hHgxphBeAEJABzaayfZ7Q4iAAsk2mehQeBgCwGHxSWOxIRkGXiACIpjBUch0UkdETErVsQdsV9ERIAPJEIHPUHxGQ+ChcW5EODsLiJOEhd54z7SQlE8xGQXCojfCAQthEZDU2lij58+VCl5EXa4yUE4lygX6zhKli8DU0ukfBnBJp1IA===), you can see that `MoveNext` calls `awaiter.GetResult()`.

To see how `Task` works here, start with [`TaskAwaiter.OnCompleted`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs,91), and see that it calls [`Task.SetContinuationForAwait`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs,222), which calls [`AddTaskContinuation`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,362aeac530811357), which ends up storing it in [`m_continuationObject`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,210). This is then invoked in [`Task.FinishContinuations`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,3601).